# Resumable upload with Google drive with php

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make a resumable upload in php with Google Drive, using this doc: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resumable

I need to do it without the sdk.

I already manage a simple upload but when I try to start a resumable session, my cURL don't return anything.

Here what my cURL looks like:

```
$curl_header = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->_token,
    'X-Upload-Content-Length: '.$total_file_size,
    'X-Upload-Content-Type: '.$mime_type
);

$datas = array();

$url_upload = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable';

$curl_default_options = array(
    // Default option (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php)
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $curl_header,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => $path_cert.'/googledrive/certificat.pem',
    CURLOPT_URL        => $url_upload,
    CURLOPT_POST       => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $datas
);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_default_options);

if (count($curl_more_options)) {
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $curl_more_options);
}
```

I did a "curl_getinfo($curl)" and got that:

```
Array ( 
    [url] => https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable 
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 
    [http_code] => 200 
    [header_size] => 699 
    [request_size] => 288 
    [filetime] => -1 
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
    [redirect_count] => 0 
    [total_time] => 0.203 
    [namelookup_time] => 0 
    [connect_time] => 0.016 
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.047 
    [size_upload] => 0 
    [size_download] => 0 
    [speed_download] => 0 
    [speed_upload] => 0 
    [download_content_length] => 0 
    [upload_content_length] => -1 
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.203 
    [redirect_time] => 0 
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 216.58.208.202 
    [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
    [primary_port] => 443 
    [local_ip] => 192.168.0.44 
    [local_port] => 56440 
)
```

Comment: did you ever solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time, but it must be something like that:

- First part upload:

  ```
  $curl_headers = array(
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'X-Upload-Content-Length: '.$total_file_size,
      'X-Upload-Content-Type: '.$mime_type
  );

  $datas = '{
      "name": "'.$name.'",
      "parents": ["'.$id_file_destination.'"]
   }';

  $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable';

  $curl_default_options = array(
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $curl_headers,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
      CURLOPT_CAINFO         => $path_cert.'/certificat.pem',
      CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
      CURLOPT_POST           => true,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $datas,
      CURLOPT_HEADER         => true
  );
  ```

You will receive a session that can be used to resume the upload:

- Resumable upload:

  ```
  $header = array(
      'Content-Length: '.$content_length,
      'Content-Type: '.$mime_type,
      'Content-Range: bytes '.$byte_start.'-'.$byte_end.'/'.$total_file_size,
  );

  $datas = fread($file, $content_length);

  $url = $session;

  $curl_default_options = array(
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $header,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
      CURLOPT_CAINFO         => $path_cert.'/certificat.pem',
      CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => 'PUT',
      CURLOPT_INFILE         => $file,
      CURLOPT_INFILESIZE     => $total_file_size,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $datas,
      CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
  );
  ```