# Creating resumable files Upload session to google drive not working via php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Am trying to create session for uploading files to google drive via **resumable** upload

**API source**
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Length: 38
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000

{
  "name": "myObject"
}
```

**Here is the definition of what all the http headers does.**

**X-Upload-Content-Type.** Optional. Set to the MIME type of the file data, which will be transferred in subsequent requests.
 If the MIME type of the data is not specified in metadata or through this header, the object will be served as 
application/octet-stream.

**X-Upload-Content-Length.** Optional. Set to the number of bytes of file data, which will be transferred in subsequent requests.

**Content-Type.** Required if you have metadata for the file. Set to application/json; charset=UTF-8.

**Content-Length.** Required unless you use chunked transfer encoding. Set to the number of bytes in the body of this initial 
request.

**Here is my code.**
 My issue is that the code will keeps on loading on the browser until it times out. 
I have increased max_exection time
severally but the same issue. I was wondering what I have done wrong with the **curl headers** or the codes itself..

```
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
    $url= 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable';
    $token='my token goes here';

    $file_name = "nancy.zip";
    echo $fsize =filesize($file_name);
    $mType='application/zip';

    echo $chunkSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // 1mb

    $datas = '{
        "name": "'.$file_name.'"
     }';
    /*
    $header=array(                                                                          
    //"Host: www.googleapis.com",                                                                                
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
    "Content-Length: $chunkSize",
    "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "X-Upload-Content-Type: $mType",
    "X-Upload-Content-Length: $fsize"
    );
    */
//ziganotschka suggestions
$header=array(
 "Authorization: Bearer".$token, 
"Content-Length: ".$chunkSize, 
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8",
 "X-Upload-Content-Type:".$mType,
 "X-Upload-Content-Length: ".$fsize ); 

    $ch=curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datas);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);


    $res = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);


    var_dump($res);
```

Comment: You seem to have a quotation issue: `header=array(                                                                          
//"Host: www.googleapis.com",                                                                                
"Authorization: Bearer".$token,
"Content-Length: ".$chunkSize,
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8",
"X-Upload-Content-Type:".$mType,
"X-Upload-Content-Length: ".$fsize
);`

Comment: Its not a quotation issue. I have tried your solution yet the browser keeps loading. no result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697635/resumable-upload-with-google-drive-with-php

Comment: Thanks alot. This is what am looking for. Thank you